# apoc.gephi.add doesn't work : NODE[25512922] has no property with propertyKey='name'

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm currently trying to set up a streaming connection between a Neo4j DB and Gephi. I use then Apoc with [apoc.gephi.add](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi).

```
match path = (p:Person)--(a:Address)
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', path) yield nodes, relationships
return nodes, relationships
limit 20
```

But I have a problem with this, whom I don't understand the cause.
[my execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgBmR.png)

So Neo4j saying me that I don't have property with propertyKey="name".

I tested the query on a movie DB previously and it worked, but there is a 'name' property in this DB so I did a new test.
When I try to reproduce the situation by creating a new movie DB without 'name' property, my query work as on the other movie DB.

I'm lost so I'm looking for help.
I'm running on neo4j 3.2.2, apoc 3.2.0.3.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: which neo4j are you using?
Judging by the code in https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.3/src/main/java/apoc/gephi/Gephi.java it should default to id of the node if no property key with name,title or label is found

Comment: the movie DB are on neo4j 3.4.4. My problem DB is in 3.2.2. But i don't find a download link for neo4j 3.2.2 to test (I don't have access to the db at the moment)

Comment: I made tests with same neo and apoc releases, and it continues to work only on movie db and not on my main db. Please notice I removed name property of movie db with a simple ctrl+f replace 'name' by 'nom' on notepad++, maybe it's not enough.