# Neo4j Gephi Cypher error: Error with cypher query on nodes without property "name"

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

This question is similar to the one asked in [apoc.gephi.add doesn't work : NODE[25512922] has no property with propertyKey='name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217565/apoc-gephi-add-doesnt-work-node25512922-has-no-property-with-propertykey-n) yet, I want to add a few things: the issue is with Neo4j 3.2.12 and APOC version 3.2.0.3, if the node does not contain the property "name" (exactly this string), then it raises the error:

> NODE[x] has no property with propertyKey='name'

Even if the node contains properties with the substring 'name' (example, "propertyname"), it throws the same error. On checking the code in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.2/src/main/java/apoc/gephi/Gephi.java, it looks like the last block of code in the method **caption(Node n)** should take care of it (the absence of a node property with string "name"). However, for some reason, it is not able to detect the substring "name" in the property names. Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: You define a property called `name`, and in fact you want Neo4j to find the property `propertyname` ? Yes this is not working . The procedure just search a property with the exact name (case-insensitive)

Comment: @logisima, you did not understand the issue - the error suggests that for the gephi to visualize the Neo4j network data, the nodes "must" have the property "name", which I think should never be the case. If it is the case now, then this is a shortcoming which should be addressed.

Comment: In fact the plugin is searching one of those properties (case insensitive) : `name`, `title`, `label`. If nothing is found, then the Gephi label will be the Neo4j's ID of the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some tests on the lastest version, and everything is working.

So I started to check the commit log of the procedure, and I have found this : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/commit/8b25b05fa461ae0177db1b0604f628b73f12e08d#diff-d27b3f05da2e50dbcd2c95ca367b0e65

So it's a bug on the procedure, but it has been correted on the version `3.2.0.4`. So you just have to upgrade your `apoc` version.